# Accessing first element of string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

It might be a newbie question but here is my problem:

I want to declare an array of strings but when I access the first element, the other elements gets concatenated with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char words[2][3] = {"foo", "bar"};
    printf("%s\n", words[0]); // I want to print foo
    printf("%s\n", words[1]); // I want to print bar
}
```

Which outputs

```
foobar
bar
```

although I was expecting

```
foo
bar
```

Can someone explain:

1. What just happened ?
2. How do I get the behaviour that I was expecting ?

Comment: You want to read on what C-"string"s are and how to handle them.

Answer (score 10):

Your array `word` doesn't have sufficient space for the null bytes at the ends of the strings and it results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you attempt to print the elements as C-string (using `%s`). Increase the array size:

```
char words[2][4] = {"foo", "bar"};
```